# Given a polynomial f(x)=x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)+1

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

Given a polynomial $f(x)=x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)+1$ and $p$ an odd prime, prove that it exists a number $n$ such that $p$ divides $f(n)$ if and only if it exists an integer $m$ such that $p$ divides $m^2-5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that

$$f(x) = x(x + 1)(x + 2)(x + 3) + 1 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Since $p$ is an odd prime, then any $n$ with $p \mid f(n)$ is true iff only $p \mid 16f(n)$. Multiply $f(n)$ by $16$ and distribute the powers of $2$ to each factor with $n$ in it to get

$$16f(n) = (2n)(2n + 2)(2n + 4)(2n + 6) + 16 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Hint: Now, let

> $$m = 2n + 3 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

to get

> $$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}16f(n) = g(m) & = (m - 3)(m - 1)(m + 1)(m + 3) + 16 \\ & = (m - 3)(m + 3)(m - 1)(m + 1) + 16 \\ & = (m^2 - 9)(m^2 - 1) + 16 \\& = m^4 - 10m^2 + 9 + 16 \\& = m^4 - 10m^2 + 25 \\ & = (m^2 - 5)^2\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Thus $p \mid (m^2 - 5)^2$ and, since $p$ is a prime, this means $p \mid m^2 - 5$.

For the other direction, for any $m$ where $p \mid m^2 - 5$, if $m$ is even, then use a new $m$ with $p$ added to it so it's odd but where you still have $p \mid m^2 - 5$. Hint for remainder of the proof:

> Then you can reverse the above steps in \eqref{eq4A} to get, from \eqref{eq3A}, that with the integer
>
> $n = \frac{m - 3}{2}$, that $p \mid 16f(n) \implies p \mid f(n)$.

Comment: @Demian $x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3) +1 = (x^2 + 3x + 1)^2 $ appears often in Olympiads.  This is a useful property to know. The hard part then was converting to $m^2 - 5$ since $x^2 + 3x + 1 != m^2 - 5$, but we have $4x^2+12x+4 = (2x+3)^2 - 5$.

Comment: Why did you chose 16?

Comment: How did you know 16 was going to help you?

Comment: @Demian For me at least, I saw there's a difference of squares among the $x$ term factors, but involving fractions with a denominator of $2$. Since the values are all supposed to be integers, by multiplying each $x$ term factor by $2$, for $2^4 = 16$ for all $4$ such factors, I was then able to deal with integers.

Comment: @CalvinLin, could it be then that for the other direction one can start saying $p|m^2-5$ and define arbitrarily that $m=(2n+3)^2-5$ for some integer $n$? That is, begin the proof defining such $m$?